# Excessive memory usage in Mixed Mode c++/CLR application

Tags: c++, .net, memory, memory-management, stack-memory

I have an native c++ application from which i am making call to .net dll(external function), I see that when i make call to managed, it allocates the full stack allocated for thread specified using /stack linker option, however if I make only native function calls, it allocates the stack it is required for the calculations.

Below are my observations

With /stack option set to 80MB, and with calls to managed external function.
[image]

With /stack option set to 1MB, and with calls to managed external function.
[image]

With /stack option set to 80MB, and with calls to native internal function.
[image]

When we make calls to .Net external function, there are also some extra threads which are related to GC. Also threads in our application are also using considerably more stack space compared to the case where we do not call .Net external function. I am not sure if managed stack is place on top of native stack. Can someone help me in understanding why full stack for a thread is allocated when we make calls to .Net external function and also memory management in mixed mode application.

Answer (score 2):

OK I finally found the answer.

The CLR always commits the whole stack memory for managed threads  as soon as a managed thread is created, or lazily when a native thread becomes a managed thread. this is done to ensure that stack overflow can be dealt with predictably by the execution engine.

In managed code, the System.Threading.Thread class's constructor provides two overloads that accepts a maxStackSize parameter. As full stack is committed at creation time for all managed threads, and so maxStackSize parameter represents both the reserve and the commit size:they are effectively same.

Just to clarify, there are three steps to using memory on the stack:

Reserve virtual address space for the stack in the process
Commit the pages
Use the pages

The default behaviour in normal Win32 programs is to do just 1 when a thread starts up. The problem with that is that the dynamic stack growth can fail under high load - you might find that when you want to add a stack frame, the system doesn't have any free virtual memory available for you.

By doing step 2, the CLR ensures that memory will be kept in reserve so that step 3 will never fail.

Any useful information regarding this are still appreciated.
Thank You.